# Does the boot partition NEED to be mounted for every OS in a multiboot situation?

Tags: linux, boot

1. I'm running multiple EFI linux systems (emphasis on EFI) on a drive.
2. One (and only one) of them has rEFInd installed on it (I have a personal aversion to GRUB).
3. Every single one of them has the EFI partition mounted.
   This configuration works just fine.

Now, if I remove the EFI system partition's entry from the fstab of every system (other than the one that has rEFInd installed), everything should be working just fine.

Why am I wrong? Or if I am correct, what precautions should I be takng?

Note: One of the systems is actually GhostBSD, so feel free to extend your answer.

Comment: One of the main reasons I felt like doing this is that most linux distributions (almost all the high level ones.. Ubuntu, Pop OS, Fedora etc) try to install grub without the option to opt out or even a warning. GhostBSD gives you the option to use its inbuilt (FreeBDS's boot0) bootloader or rEFInd. I wish the linux distributions were like that by default.

Comment: I think the mount of the ESP, is so that if there are updates, it knows where to put those updates. But the parts of boot loaders in the ESP are rarely updated.